# How to improve control of hand whilst drawing on tablet?

Tags: drawing

I got a tablet yesterday and had been drawing for almost 2 hours straight, drawing over the outline of already drawn figures in photoshop. I have always wanted to draw so when I saw a sale of a tablet for 35 euro's I went for it.

The problem is, I can create some nice lines but when I get to the end of the line my hand makes a wierd movement. I tried controlling it by focusing more but that didn't help either.

What do i need to do to make my movements smooth and gain more control of my hand?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might seem like a cop-out answer, but... practice! Practice is the main way for you to improve your control and line quality. I've been using a drawing tablet for 10 years and I still make mistakes.

The key to drawing lines is to use long, quick strokes rather than trying to hold your hand steady while you trace your outline. Each stroke will likely take several tries, so don't feel bad if you don't get it right away!

If you find you need further assistance, software like [Lazy Nezumi](https://lazynezumi.com/) will stabilize your strokes, giving you much smoother lines in general.

Lastly, as @whrrgarbl pointed out, make sure that your tablet is calibrated properly and that your drivers are up to date.

Comment: +1 for Lazy Nezumi.  That looks like a very helpful software.

Comment: +1 - The only thing I would add is make sure your tablet is calibrated properly! It may seem obvious but I've had issues in the past with my pressure sensitivity going out of whack, which makes a big difference in how it feels to draw.

Comment: @whrrgarbl very true! Also to make sure drivers are updated - will edit my answer to include this

Comment: +1 - While practice is good, remember that when you are tired, details will get harder. Do not worry if at the end of a long day you make more mistakes or get worse results.

Comment: That software is amazing! I used it and will defenitely buy it when the trial runs out. I have now just been practicing control with my hand by drawing the oultine of existing cartoon characters. The rounded objects were the hardest but that software helped me with that! Thanks!

Comment: @whrrgarbl I dont believe the tablet can be "calibrated". Its  a 35 euro tablet and the drivers are up to date. I went through the app it came with but there are no calibration options.

Comment: @Granny Don't forget to check in whatever drawing program you are using, there may be brush options available there too. But yes the cheaper versions generally have less options.

Comment: @whrrgarbl I am using Photoshop CC, i have also bought a set of premade brushes from a youtuber who i like to watch.

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix: get a Matt screen display protector like for a tablet. The added texture is enough to give your drawing surface a bit of extra ***tooth***. I did this on an iPad Pro and it changed the experience to one of utter joy. Really, it helped very much.

Do the application of the protective foil in a humid room like the bathroom after taking a long hot shower so you don’t get bubbles, and make sure to really clean the surface beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

*[edit: misunderstood initial question, so please disregard answer... unless it’s of use to you. Answered from the point of view of someone who uses a stylus to draw on a tablet not a finger]*

Try holding the pen (stylus) higher up (away from the ‘nib’) and moving the stylus using your shoulder and elbow.

The ‘weird’ move is quite possibly down to your wrist. Wrists are fantastically flexible, but sometimes that works against you. For flowing, fluid movements control a pen/stylus/brush from as high up your arm as possible holding the wrist stable.

...and, as @jackwise says, practice.

Comment: Where did you find a stylus or pen mentioned in the question? Most people use their fingers on a tablet.

Comment: @Willeke my mistake. I misunderstood the initial question. Editing my response to note this. Thanks!

Comment: I use a pen. I dont think i will be able to draw with my finger any better then with the pen :)

Comment: @Granny - in that case, the ‘draw from the shoulder’ tip is definitely worth a try. It feels incradibly awkward and counterintuitive at first, but you’ll be drawing smooth, controlled lines in no time. Hope you’re having fun with the tablet.